# Span is smaller than the parent div, why?

Tags: html, css

Why is the span smaller than it's parent div?

```css
.class1 {
  background-color: red;
  border: solid thin;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.class1 span {
  background-color: yellow;
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">
  <span>DRAWBACK</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Note- I have added the code from the link into your question- you will likely attract less favourable attention / feedback if you dont include the relevant code in the question itself

Answer (score 2):

The reason is the nature of the default [**`display`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) style for both `div` and `span` elements.

> The `display` CSS property specifies the type of rendering box used for
>   an element. In HTML, default display property values are taken from
>   behaviors described in the HTML specifications or from the
>   browser/user default stylesheet. The default value in XML is inline.

`div` elements are block level elements (respect dimension, take full width by default) `span` elements are `inline` elements (content determines dimension, for all purposes handled in a similar way to text).

As such, you will want to match the two display types by setting `display:block` to the child `span`. Alternatively, as the `span` is no longer behaving like a span should, change it to a `div`

```css
.class1 {
  background-color: red;
  border: solid thin;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.class1 span {
  background-color: yellow;
  font-size: 60px;
  display: block; /* <---- add this */ 
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">
  <span>DRAWBACK</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because DIV element is block. SPAN element is not block.

If you need your span to take up the whole space of it's parent div element, set it's `display: block` in CSS:

```css
.class1{
    background-color:red;
    border:solid thin;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

.class1 span{
    background-color:yellow;
    font-size:60px;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">
    <span>DRAWBACK</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/3rfkck1d/1/

```
.class1 span{
    background-color:yellow;
    font-size:60px;
    display:inherit;
}
```

You have to use display:inherit;

Comment: thanks so much, can you tell me now why i should use inherit? span is inline but div is block element.

Comment: Because DIV element is block. SPAN element is not block.